# Java swing : return value to another method when button clicked

Tags: button, click, return

I have a text box and button and when the button is clicked, I want to send/return the value of text field to another method but how can I get this as the value will not be returned because it is not called from another method.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String name=jTextField4.getText();
    return name;
}
```

I want this value to be received by another method() in another class.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use [ActionListeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)